# Custom date format in javascript form date format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

I have the date `2013-03-10` how can i get `March 10,2013`. I tried a lot with Date function in javascript but can't get correct format as given above.Help should be appreciated.

Comment: Please share what you have already tried. Also, a tip: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: if you're happy to use momentjs, I would strongly recommend that for handling dates in javascript - https://momentjs.com/ - look under the 'format' section

Comment: [Every single possible JavaScript date parsing or formatting question has already been asked and answered](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+format+date). Please **search** before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: @HuwDavies i wast to use only basic javascript and their Date() functions.

Comment: I searched a lot can you please mention a link in comment @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Date.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) :

```js
var options = { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' }

console.log( new Date('2013-03-10').toLocaleString('en-US', options) )
```

Comment: can you please tell me if i put date with time then how can i get like March 10, 2013, 7:30 PM @Slai

Comment: @CodeBreaker you can check the link in my answer for the other options, and don't ask more than one question per question

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this question simply because I would like to share that it is not necessary to use the `Date` object nor heavy libraries like MomentJS if all you need is to support those two formats.

The solution is basically this:

1. Prepare a mapping between month number and month names.
2. Break the input date in YYYY-MM-DD format into its individual components (e.g., split with '-')
3. Get the month name from the map constructed in step 1.
4. Reconstruct the date in target format using simple string interpolation.

Something like this:

```
var MONTH_NAMES = {
  1: 'January',
  2: 'February',
  3: 'March',
  ....
};

function convertDateFormat(inputDate) {
  var components = inputDate.split('-');
  var year = components[0];
  var month = MONTH_NAMES[components[1]];
  var day = components[2];
  return month + ' ' + day + ', ' + year;
}

convertDateFormat('2013-03-10');
```